# How can I access the value for the bottom SafeArea padding under the bottom navigation bar from a different file?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigationbar

I've implemented a Navigation Bar Handler class that has a body of an IndexedStack widget.
Below the NavBarHandler class is MyHomePage. What I'm wanting to do is evaluate the screen height in MyHomePage and then lay out the screen accordingly. Specifically, I'm needing exact screen height availability for landscape orientation so that the screen will either implement a Column or a SingleChildScrollView.

```
class NavBarHandler extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavBarHandler({super.key});

  @override
  State<NavBarHandler> createState() => _NavBarHandlerState();
}

class _NavBarHandlerState extends State<NavBarHandler> {
  int _navBarIndex = 0;

  final _buildBody = <Widget>[
    const MyHomePage(),
    const CampusMapScreen(),
    const SportsScreen(),
    const DirectoryScreen(),
  ];

  final List<Widget> _navBarItems = [
    const NavigationDestination(
      // selectedIcon: ,
      icon: Icon(Icons.home),
      label: 'Home',
    ),
    const NavigationDestination(
      icon: Icon(Icons.map),
      label: 'Map',
    ),
    const NavigationDestination(
      icon: Icon(Icons.sports_baseball),
      label: 'Sports',
    ),
    const NavigationDestination(
      icon: Icon(Icons.store_mall_directory),
      label: 'Directory',
    ),
  ];

  void _navItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _navBarIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        labelBehavior: NavigationDestinationLabelBehavior.onlyShowSelected,
        destinations: _navBarItems,
        onDestinationSelected: _navItemTapped,
        selectedIndex: _navBarIndex,
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(   // _buildBody[_navBarIndex], the alternative
        index: _navBarIndex,
        children: _buildBody,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's MyHomePage:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  final screenWidgetsHeight = 385;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appBarHeight = AppBar().preferredSize.height;
    final safeAreaTop = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    final safeAreaBottom = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom;
    final maxScreenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    final availableScreenHeight = maxScreenHeight -
        (appBarHeight +
            safeAreaTop +
            safeAreaBottom +
            kBottomNavigationBarHeight +
            2);
    print('safeAreaBottom: $safeAreaBottom');
    print('height = $availableScreenHeight');

More code...
```

The problem from MyHomePage is that safeAreaBottom is always 0 so therefore, I am unable to determine the exact available screen height. What I'm needing to do is access the Scaffold padding that is under the NavigationBar housed in NavBarHandler from MyHomePage.

I've tried setting up a Provider and using context.watch() but got an error saying essentially that by doing that I'm telling a widget to rebuild that's already rebuilding when orientation changes.
I've tried passing values in the constructor for MyHomePage but that doesn't update the state like it needs to.
I'm really not sure how to move forward here.